# A probability question with and without information about distribution

Tags: probability, distributions, self-study, normal-distribution

Employees of company XYZ travel an average of 28 km per day to the office, with a standard deviation of 8 km.

- Assuming a normal distribution of miles traveled, determine the percentage of employees who travel between 20 and 36 km per day.
- Explain what conclusions you might draw in the absence of information on the distribution.

## Try

The phenomenon is a normal distribution: $X \thicksim N(\mu,\sigma^2)$.

The values of the population are $\mu = 28$ and $\sigma = 8$.

The probability of the event $\{20 < X < 36\}$ has calculated as follow:
$$
P(20 < X < 36) \approx P\left( \frac{20 - 28}{8} < Z < \frac{36-28}{8} \right) = P(-1 < Z < 1)
$$

$$
= \Phi(1) - \Phi(-1) = \Phi(1) - [1 - \Phi(1)] = 0.8413 - 0.1587 = 0.6826
$$

The point is that I wouldn't know what conclusions to draw in the absence of distribution information, that is, without saying that $X$ followed a probability distribution.

How can I write it down? Do you have any advice for me?

Thank you.

**Update**

About the second point of the exercise, I should use the Chebyshev's inequality. But I notice that the multiple of the standard deviation is $k=1$. Besides, the ratio $1 - 1/k^2$ it would be null.

How should I proceed? Should I calculate the probability according to the formula?

Comment: You might want to look at Chebyshev's inequality

Comment: @Henry thinking about it you're right because it uses both sample statistics. I'll edit the question to add the inequality. Thank you.

Comment: There aren't any sample statistics in this question.  It is indeed reasonable to suppose that the numbers 28 and 8 originally were obtained from a set of observations, but then there's exceptionally little you can say, because you would need to know how those observations were selected and how many of them there were.  This is the kind of thing that makes some textbook questions problematic: they can force you into performing analyses that you would never do in the real world.

Comment: @whuber I may have misspelled "sample statistics", I fix immediately. But your opinion about textbooks it's not quite wrong at all because some are "fictitious" for educational purposes though they may be inspired by reality.